# JQ Grid - savings edits

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Is there anyway to have JQGrid "remember" edits made on page 1 when a user goes to page 2 (or any other page)?

I have not found an easy work-around to this issue, particularly when we have many, many rows of data.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look into the [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) features of jqGrid. They include event handlers that are fired when data is changed in the cell. These will send the changes to your server and update your data store.